# Windows Application to extract Video & multimedia content from PDFs

Tags: windows, video, pdf, data-extraction

There seems to be a tool called [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) on Mac OSX but I couldn't find a way or a tool to do so on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use the library [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/):

- open source (Apache License v2.0)
- ability to extract content from documents (e.g. [images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8705163/395857))

Comment: I specifically need to extract videos - Does it do that? And was looking for Application, hopefully not having to write code - Then I'd have to learn & formulate scripts or programs to use such a library. Any easy scripts?